# Power Bi - change value of the parameters used in web request (api + json)

Tags: json, api, powerbi, webrequest

It is possible to change value of the parameters in Power Bi Desktop from dashboard (main-page) level ?
I'm using parameters in two web requests as json body (DateFrom DateTo).

I know that there is "Transform data" option and I was trying :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-dynamic-m-query-parameters
but I cannot bind table to parameter - there is no "Bind to parameter" field.

[Bind to parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZnSr.png)

[My Api Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfHU4.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can only use query parameters in Power Query (`M` language). Here is an example that works for me. Assuming the output is JSON, you would do it like this (you do it in the advanced editor):

```
let
  src = Web.Contents(baseUrl, [RelativePath = urlPath, Query=[#"api_token" = apiKey, limit=Text.From(limit), start=Text.From(offset)]])
  json = Json.Document(src)
in
  json
```

In the above examples, parameters are:

- baseUrl for root API path
- urlPath for API endpoint
- apiKey for API authorization token
- limi and offset for getting a subset of data

That's just an example, but the `api_token` parameter is crucial, if you want the query to refresh in the Power BI Service (assuming you're using token-based authentication).

**EDIT:**

So, I think I finally understood where your problem is. I don't think it can be done with REST API, as the requirement for the Bind parameter function to work is for the query to be in `Direct Query` mode as opposed to `Import`. And I don't think you can set it for this.